# Cómo ingresar variables de registro en sesión PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, php7, variables-globales

He registrado desde un formulario en PHP a una base de datos en MYSQL y el código que recoje los datos es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros (nombre, email, contraseña) VALUES ('$nombre', 
'$email', '$contraseña')";
?>
```

Y para el inicio de sesión el login.php envía los datos "email" y "contraseña" a loguear.php y lo valida con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM registros where email = 
'$email' and contraseña = '$contraseña'";

$bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
$parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
if($parametros['contar']>0){
$_SESSION['username'] = $email;
header("location: ../bienvenida.php");
}else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
?>
```

Una vez realizada la validación y hubo éxito me dirige a bienvenida.php

```
    <div class="container">
    <?php
    session_start();
    $sesion = $_SESSION['username'];
    if(!isset($sesion)){
    header("location: login.php");
    }else{
    echo "<center><h4> BIENVENIDO $sesion </h></center><br>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo incluir la variable '$nombre' en el inicio de sesión correspondiente en bienvenida.php?, ya que si sólo la mando llamar me devuelve el error
 Notice: Undefined variable: $nombre

```
<h1>Tu nómbre es: <?php echo $nombre; ?> </h1>
```

Comment: Puedes hacer lo mismo que hiciste con el correo: $_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre; pero agrega session_start(); en el insert

Comment: Lo intentaré pero a que Insert te refieres?

Comment: Estas usando el dato del nombre en el archivo donde haces el insert (donde recoges los datos), entonces agrega session_start(); y crea la variable session: $_SESSION['usuario']= $nombre; o $_POST['nombre'];  Luego en tu h1 la muestras: <?php echo $_SESSION['usario']?>

Comment: @mafu sigue sin reconocerme la variable 'usuario'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas recomendable es que recuperes la información necesaria usando el query a la base de datos, PE:

```
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM registros where email = '$email' and contraseña = '$contraseña'";
```

Puedes validar usando la función mysql_num_rows para saber el numero de resultados que te ha regresado MySQL

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($bdconect) > 0)
```

Seguido, almacenas los datos que requieras en la variable de sesión.

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);// O en su defecto también puedes usar fetch_row
$_SESSION['username'] = $email;
$_SESSION['name'] = $res['nombre'];
```

Editado.

En bienvenida.php deberías tener algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        session_start();
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        if(!isset($username)){
            header("location: login.php");
        }else{
            echo "<center><h4> BIENVENIDO $username </h></center><br>";
            echo "<center><h4> Nombre: $name </h></center><br>";
        }
     ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @NebulaKnight he intentado lo que me dices pero sigue sin reconocerme la variable.

Comment: Hola, una duda, tienes entonces problemas con que no te reconoce la variable $nombre por que no esta definida? Agrego un poco mas de información.

Comment: así es, una vez que logro iniciar sesión me dirige a bienvenida.php y ahí es dónde trato de llamar la variable nombre y me marca el error dentro de mi html, pero si me carga la página

Comment: Yo quiero añadir el valor de la variable nombre, fuera del else en un div aparte

Comment: ok, independientemente de si colocas el div dentro o fuera del if va a terminar dándote el mismo resultado, en caso de que no existe la variable $username te va a reedirigir a tu login y no vas a ver el div

Comment: Con respecto a $nombre, una vez se termina de ejecutar tu primer código deja de existir esto debido al recolector de basura de PHP, por ello necesitas guardar el valor en alguna parte como en la variable de sesión y recuperarlo después, checa la modificación que coloque del archivo bienvenida.php y lo que había colocado previamente sobre la consulta a base de datos y el almacenamiento en la variable de sesión.

Comment: El error me lo esta marcando en el if "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_num_rows() in "

Comment: Debajo de la consulta que cambie como me dijiste, tengo algo así:                     $bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
$parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
if(mysql_num_rows($bdconect) > 0){
   $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['name'] = $parametros['nombre'];
  header("location: ../bienvenida.php");                                                         }else {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
    window.location.href="../login.php";
    </script>';
}

Comment: Disculpa mi error, la función es mysqli_num_rows(), me falto poner una "i". Agrego documentación de la función https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: GRACIAS amigo @NebulaKnight por tomarte el tiempo, tu procedimiento terminó funcionandome, GRACIAS DE NUEVO¡